# How to get more than 25 items via Simplepie RSS Feeds?

Tags: rss, feed, simplepie

I have a feed with 50 items but seemingly no matter what I do, it always returns just 25.

`$feed->set_item_limit(50);` or `$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0,50);` none of these have any effect nor do I see any reference to the number 25 in the class source, I don't get it.

The feed is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/silviavaldemoros/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile&max-results=50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/feed.php');
    $rss = fetch_feed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/silviavaldemoros/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile&max-results=50');
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(50);

    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    print_r($rss_items);
```

Try this code..

Comment: My feed URL was htmlentities encoded which made it disregard the & bits of the URL -.- And YouTube v2 api sends 25 items by default. Your answer made me realize that I did it correctly but the URL was bad.